# Qtdesinger, ruby and some action for buttons/widgets in generated code

Tags: ruby, qt-designer, qtruby

I am developing an application using ruby and qt as front end. I used qtdesigner to draw gui and converted the code using rbuic4. But i am unable get any action for buttons placed on main programm. I created main.rb and called generated code using require  './muprogramm.rb'. Here is the sample code for opening file dialog for button mbusb_close (object name)

```
require  './muprogramm.rb'
require 'Qt4'
class Form < Qt::Widget
    slots 'file_dialog()'
    def initialize(parent = nil)
    super
        @ui = Ui_Frame.new
        @ui.setupUi(self)
        Qt::Object.connect(@ui.mbusb_close, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self, SLOT('file_dialog()'))
    end
    def file_dialog
        f = Qt::FileDialog
        text = File.new(f.getOpenFileName).read
        #@ui.editor_window.setText 'WikiBooks: Ruby'
    end
end
 a = Qt::Application.new(ARGV)
    u = Ui_Frame.new
    w = Qt::Frame.new
    u.setupUi(w)
    w.show
 a.exec
```

The resource available in the net is vague. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Just use the subclass that you created directly:

```
require  './muprogramm.rb'
require 'Qt4'
class Form < Qt::Widget
    slots 'file_dialog()'
    def initialize(parent = nil)
    super
        @ui = Ui_Frame.new
        @ui.setupUi(self)
        Qt::Object.connect(@ui.mbusb_close, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self, SLOT('file_dialog()'))
    end
    def file_dialog
        f = Qt::FileDialog
        text = File.new(f.getOpenFileName).read
        #@ui.editor_window.setText 'WikiBooks: Ruby'
    end
end
 a = Qt::Application.new(ARGV)
    w = Form.new
    w.show
 a.exec
```